# Can't Connect to Mac Postgres Instance from CentOS VM with VirtualBox

Tags: macos, postgresql, centos, virtualbox

I am able to ssh into my Mac from my VM and visa versa. I am also able to view web pages hosted on my CentOS VM in a browser on my Mac. However, when trying to connect to a Postgres DB on my Mac from my VM in a Node App I am trying to fire up, I get the following message:

> no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.56.101"

I did not seem to have a pg_hba.conf file on my server, so I installed Postgres 9.3 and various PGAdmin packages for working with PHP from [Here](http://www.jnvilo.com/cms/sysadmin/databases/postgresql/install-phppgadmin-on-centos-7). I did not think I would need the installation since I am looking to connect to a DB on another machine - technically. I figured I'd install more than I need and try to get it working. Upon looking to restart postgres services I get this error:

> Job for postgresql-9.3.service failed. See 'systemctl status
>   postgresql-9.3.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

Anyone know how to proceed from here? I Googled the error to no avail. There seems to be something wrong with my Postges installation. I have tried re-installing to no avail.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The pg_hba.conf file is located on the server, it defines access rules for the databases the server hosts.  It is usually located in

/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/

The directory after postgresql will change depending on the version of postgres installed on the server.  Once you have made the necissary changes to the pg_hba.conf file you will need to restart or reload your postgresql server instance.

If the file isn't located there, have you installed it with some package manager? (like port), might be worth checking to see where it installs software, perhaps something like /opt ?  been a while since I used postgresql under OSX and I don't have access to an instance at the moment, sorry.

Other possible locations I found with some googling:

```
/opt/local/etc/postgresql/
or possibly 
/Library/PostgreSQL/
```

You may also be able to use OSXs Spotlight to find the location of the file.

HTH

Comment: 1. This is happening on my CentOS VM not OSX. 2. I have made the needed changes as recommended by the like in my questions. 3) upon restarting is when I am seeing the second error on CentOS v7. I have Postges installed and working on OSX. CentOS is where the problem lies. Thanks

Comment: So you are seeing the error message on the client machine attempting to connect to the database server?  But there is an entry on the database server in the pg_hba file for the IP address of the client machine (in this case I imagine the Centos VM Has IP address of 192.168.56.101) ?  Is the Mac the postgres db server or another machine?

Comment: Question 1 - Yes. The entry for the pg_hba file in on the client CentOS machine. The IP entered is for my Mac's IP - this is so that CentOS can access my Mac when trying to connect. Postgres is working on my Mac. I was trying to also install Postgres on CentOS and restart it. Failed.

Comment: The goal is to get an App on my CentOS VM to connect to a database on my Mac OS. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: The pg_hba file has to be on the server not the client.  The pg_hba file tells the sever the IP address of clients that are permitted to access it.  Putting it on the client will have no effect.

Comment: Ah, I will give that a try then. Thanks.

Comment: I just had a quick google and found that the file may be in a few places on the Mac depending on the installation.  /opt/local/etc  or possibly /Library/PostgrSQL/9.1/   You may find it easier to use a terminal on the mac to find the file, as the Finder may hide those locations unless you open them directly (Command-G IIRC)